# Undo community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

I didn't understand the community wiki at first. So I checked it for all my answers. Is there any way to undo it? And there should be an explanation (tooltip?) under it.

Comment: there isn't a way to undo wiki :)

Comment: A subject for meta, though it will be closed as a duplicate there...

Comment: Lmao what a dumbass, if you don't want reputation, go ahead and check that box.

Answer (score 2):

Community Wiki is permanent and irrevocable.

The tooltip when you hover your mouse over the checkbox is also fairly self-explanatory:

[image]

> Community owned posts do not generate any reputation for the owner, have a lower reputation barrier for collaborative editing, and show only a revision history instead of a signature block.