# How to undo community wiki made by five people editing the same post?

Tags: support, edits, community-wiki

When five different people edit the same post it's automatically made community wiki.

Can this process be undone somehow so the post is not wiki? I tried to rollback my edit but no luck.. this is the post in question: [Is it possible to use a <caption> tag in a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990300/is-it-possible-to-use-a-caption-tag-in-a-form)

Comment: You can't: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69017/undo-community-wiki

Comment: @marcog thanks, JS didn't work on Meta for a while so related questions never loaded.

Comment: Well, it's not exact duplicate - in my case nobody explicitly made it wiki, it was done automatically without ever warning me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now possible by flagging the question.

[Reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373).

> community moderators, at their discretion, can now remove community wiki status from particular posts.

Comment: as an example of how it works - particular recent case of successful CW status removal request at Programmers Meta: [remove CW status for this answer? (hashing algorithms testing by Ian Boyd)](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3527/remove-cw-status-for-this-answer-hashing-algorithms-testing-by-ian-boyd)

Comment: Thanks @gnat this is indeed good example of proper usage of this power. :)

Answer (score 4):

No, but that's what CW is for — when it's no longer the work of a single author, but a result of the effort of multiple community members. Given how much the post has changed, community wiki is the right status for it.

Comment: Of course, in rare cases like this the community never intended to edit it five times - all of our edits collided

Comment: I agree with @YiJ on that..... maybe if the edits were made within short time span don't make it wiki? In that particular case the edits were minor, some fixed the title, some the grammar and I fixed the common mistake of putting `<taghere>` without formatting..